# Flash Builder 4.6 - ComboBox set to visible on underlying component MouseOver, but flickers when MouseOver of ComboBox

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox, flash-builder

I have a ComboBox that is set to be visible when a component that lies beneath it is hovered, my problem is that when I hover over the ComboBox it starts flickering because I am leaving the underlying component.

My code is:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function videoRollOut():void
        {
            controls.visible=false;
        }
        private function videoRollOver():void
        {
            controls.visible=true;
        }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Canvas width="100%" height="46%">
    <mx:VideoDisplay id="localVideoDisplay" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" left="0" height="100%" width="100%" rollOver="videoRollOver()" rollOut="videoRollOut()"/>  
    <s:VGroup id="controls" bottom="10" right="0" left="0" horizontalAlign="center" visible="false" mouseOver="videoRollOver()" mouseOut="videoRollOut()">
        <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle">
            <s:Label color="0xFFFFFF" text="Audio: "/>
            <s:ComboBox id="micSelection" change="micChanged(event)"
            dataProvider="{micNames}"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle">
            <s:Label color="0xFFFFFF" text="Video: "/>
            <s:ComboBox id="cameraSelection" change="cameraChanged(event)"
            dataProvider="{cameraNames}"/>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
</mx:Canvas>
```

I attempted to add the same mouseOver and mouseOut functions to the ComboBox, and while I could now hover over the ComboBox without it flickering, when I tried to hover over some of the options it would leave both the ComboBox and the VideoDisplay, making the ComboBox once again invisible however keeping the options of the ComboBox visible.

I attempted to add a mouseEnabled="false" mouseChildren="false" to the ComboBox, however the ComboBox was then unusable.

If anyone has any advice that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in your videoRollOut method

```
controls.visible=controls.getBounds(this).contains(mouseX,mouseY)?true:false;
```

Comment: Great, so that's good progress. With that it doesn't go away if I leave the video box, however it also doesn't go away if I click out of it (outside of video) without selecting an option or if I select an option outside of the videobox. Any tips on fixing this?

Comment: Oh may be we need to check that when combo box closed. I will update answer as soon I get to my machine